# docker registry local com o erro: No such image: localhost:5000

Tags: docker

Bom dia a todos,

Estou com um problema há dois dias que não estou conseguindo resolver.
Montei um ambiente com 3 máquinas, com docker swarm, uma máquina manager e dois nós.

O problema, quando vou iniciar um serviço no manager, tenho o erro: No such image: localhost:5000/integracao-toa

Eu tentei criar o registry local na máquina manager de duas formas:

**1 - como serviço**

```
docker service create --name registry --publish published=5000,target=5000,mode=host registry:2
```

Como serviço, eu não consigo dar push da imagem:

```
[root@tslxdocker-hlg docker]# docker service create --name registry --publish published=5000,target=5000,mode=host registry:2
1z0a64ulmdvu6f2k08omgg3fj
overall progress: 1 out of 1 tasks
1/1: running   [==================================================>]
verify: Service converged
[root@tslxdocker-hlg docker]# docker push localhost:5000/integracao-toa
The push refers to repository [localhost:5000/integracao-toa]
Get http://localhost:5000/v2/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: connection refused
```

Como serviço, tenho o erro de connection refused.
Porém, nas duas outras máquinas hosts, eu consigo conectar no registry:

```
curl localhost:5000/v2/_catalog
{"repositories":[]}
```

criei o arquivo /etc/docker/daemon.json e reiniciei o serviço do docker

```
[root@tslxdocker-hlg docker]# cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
    "insecure-registries":[
        "localhost:5000",
        "127.0.0.1:5000"
    ]
}
```

também tentei comentar a linha "localhost" no /etc/hosts
O erro persiste

**2 - como um container**

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

Como um simples container, eu consigo dar um push da imagem no registry, porém, os demais nodes não conseguem se conectar no registro:

push da imagem com sucesso:

```
[root@tslxdocker-hlg docker]# docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
397f6fe083da78d5d0f08be3dfa336c01e328d8bbd46637dd52ac5b479a48c11
[root@tslxdocker-hlg docker]# docker push localhost:5000/integracao-toa
The push refers to repository [localhost:5000/integracao-toa]
82c687db4923: Pushed
fe849f218079: Pushed
bd029db62750: Pushed
03861ebeff3b: Pushed
286ab5bbe85e: Pushed
de2051a29c4c: Pushed
bac22f4e2b6a: Pushed
538ca12fd712: Pushed
f75e64f96dbc: Pushed
8f7ee6d76fd9: Pushed
c23711a84ad4: Pushed
90d1009ce6fe: Pushed
latest: digest: sha256:a6adadccfc2914d4a88f74cd8fba58105d223596e5b32ef7f71754056817e3f4 size: 2849
```

Falha ao adicionar o serviço no swarm:

```
 docker service create --name integracao-toa --constraint node.labels.group==group01 --replicas 2 -p 3000:80 localhost:5000/integracao-toa
u1fwfqjs1vn1ml8665vbprzov
overall progress: 0 out of 2 tasks
1/2: No such image: localhost:5000/integracao-toa:latest@sha256:a6adadccfc2914d…
2/2: No such image: localhost:5000/integracao-toa:latest@sha256:a6adadccfc2914d…
```

interessante também que, como container, os nós também não conseguem se conectar no registry:

```
curl localhost:5000/v2/_catalog
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:5000; Connection refused
```

Então, não sei mais o que fazer e ainda tenho uma dúvida, qual é a forma mais correta de executar o registry local? como serviço ou com docker run?

**Edit 1**
No docker info me retorna a lista de registros não seguros (insecure-registries)

```
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.1:5000
 localhost:5000
 10.0.0.77:5000
 127.0.0.0/8
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver.

**Solução:**

O arquivo daemon.json deve ser configurado também nos workers e não apenas no manager.

Eu também alterei o nome da imagem de localhost:5000 para 10.0.0.77:5000 (ip do manager)

/etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
    "insecure-registries":[
        "10.0.0.77:5000"
    ]
}
```

**Em resumo**

Nos workers, eu criei o arquivo daemon.json com o insecure-registries e reiniciei o docker

No manager, executei o registry como um container mesmo.

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 registry:2
```

Criei uma nova tag da imagem (não usei latest pois quero saber qual versão exatamente está sendo executada, pelo Portainer)
    docker tag integracao-toa:14 10.0.0.77:5000/integracao-toa:14

Enviei via push para o registry local a imagem:

```
docker push 10.0.0.77:5000/integracao-toa:14
```

Executei o serviço da minha aplicação e utilizei o "contraint" para que fosse publicado somente nos workers (eu adicionei um label chamado group=group01 nos dois workers, assim,posso controlar pelo manager em quais máquinas minha aplicação fará o deploy)

```
docker service create --name integracao-toa --constraint node.labels.group==group01 --replicas 2 -p 3000:80 10.0.0.77:5000/integracao-toa:14
```

e novamente, executei com a tag específica da versão 14, ao invés da latest, assim consigo visualizar de forma mais consistente a versão sendo executada em cada nó

[image: nós executando, visualizando pelo Portainer]